# How to make a encryption of AES128 between iOS to C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, encryption

I try to make Encryption using AES128(CBC Mode) on iPhone 
and send to ASPX(GET parameter) on Windwos Server using BASE64, 
and Decryption on Windwos Server(C# .NET)

I have same KEY and IV on iPhone app and ASPX made by openssl command.

The problem is can't decryption on ASPX.

Here is my iOS Source

```
- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    memset(keyPtr, 0, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    memset(ivPtr, 0, sizeof(ivPtr));
    [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesCrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesCrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesCrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

And Using like this..

```
    NSString* keyStr = @"898698E7E5E432534B55FC1B18A*****";
    NSString* ivStr = @"FE3E758444C0F2B7EAE8F5771E*****";

    NSString *email_str = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *) [email.text UTF8String] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *emailData = [email_str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *pass_str = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *) [pass.text UTF8String] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *passData = [pass_str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSData *enEmailData = [emailData AES128EncryptWithKey:keyStr iv:ivStr];
    NSData *enPassData = [passData AES128EncryptWithKey:keyStr iv:ivStr];



    NSLog(@"Email -> %@ : %@", email.text, [enEmailData base64EncodedString]);
    NSLog(@"Pass -> %@ : %@", pass.text, [enPassData base64EncodedString]);
```

I just wanna know what is different between iOS Encryption to C# Encryption.

Please give me some information of this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `AES128Operation:` a category on NSData? Why? At a minimum give all category methods a unique prefix. At best do not use categories on API classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES on iOS meets the standard as I'm sure C# does as well, the difference is in the usage (your code).

Just for starters in your example

- The key is 256 bits, should be 128 bits
- The iv is 248 bits, it should be 128 bits
- The key size provided is `kCCBlockSizeAES128` it should be `kCCKeySizeAES128`
- No test data or results are shown in the question.

The most common issues are:

1. AES works with data and many usages have strings as input and/or output.
2. The strings are many times not ascii so there may be coding problems such as UTF8 vs UTF16.
3. Different padding of the data.
4. Incorrectly sized key and/or iv that some systems pad (Hi php).
5. Combination of pre and post encodings such as Base64

Suggestions:

- NSLog at every step.
- Start with a very simple case on easy platform:
- Use data, preferably from a file that is exactly the same on both sides, this removes conversion and display issues of the test data.
- Use simple full size key, full size iv, data of exactly one block size,
  no padding.
- With the simplest case working start adding complexity
  one step at a time.

Finally, security with encryption only needs **one bug** to be broken and exploitable and that means in the entire system including key management. Get you design reviewed by a domain expert, I do. Best yet have a domain expert create the security scheme and write the code.

Best not to add categories on NSData, but if you do prefix the method names.
It is not necessary to use chars for the data, just use NSData, ex:

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       symmetricKey.bytes, 
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes, dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCrypt status: %d", ccStatus);
        return nil;
    }
    dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    return dataOut;
}
```