# How do I get the key from the NSData object into the key/iv array for Crypto++?

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I am trying to make a Objective-C wrapper class for some cryptographic operations that will use the Crypto++ library. I have a few questions,

This is the code I am using

```
- (void)testSerpentEncryptonMechanism
{
     byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

    ::memset( key, 0x50 , CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH );
    ::memset( iv, 0x10, CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE );

    NSString *andThisShalBeEncrypted = @"Serpentine and black...";

    NSLog(@"will encrypt %@",andThisShalBeEncrypted);

    NSString *encrypted = [self encryptWithSerpentString:andThisShalBeEncrypted withKey:key];

    NSLog(@"encrypted:%@",encrypted);

    NSString *decrypted = [self decryptWithSerpentString:encrypted withKey:key andIV:iv];

    NSLog(@"decrypted: %@",decrypted);


}

- (NSString *)encryptWithSerpentString:(NSString *)plaintext withKey:(byte[])keyArray
{
    std::string ptext = [plaintext UTF8String];
    std::string ciphertext;

    byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

    ::memset( key, 0x50 , CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH );
    ::memset( iv, 0x10, CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE );

    CryptoPP::Serpent::Encryption serpentEncryptor (key, CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcSerpentEncryptor (serpentEncryptor, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfSerpentEncryptor(cbcSerpentEncryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink (ciphertext));
    stfSerpentEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ptext.c_str() ), ptext.length() + 1);
    stfSerpentEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    std::string finalCT;
    CryptoPP::StringSource base64Encoder (ciphertext, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(finalCT)));



    return @(finalCT.c_str());
}

- (NSString *)decryptWithSerpentString:(NSString *)ciphertext withKey:(byte[])keyArray andIV:(byte[])initializationVector
{
    std::string ctext;
    std::string plaintext;

    byte key[ CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE ];

//    ::memset( key, &keyArray , CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH );
//    ::memset( iv, (byte[])initializationVector, CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE );

    ::memset( key, 0x50 , CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH );
    ::memset( iv, 0x10, CryptoPP::Serpent::BLOCKSIZE );

    // decode from base64
    std::string encoded = [ciphertext UTF8String];
    CryptoPP::StringSource base64Encoder (encoded, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(ctext)));


    CryptoPP::Serpent::Decryption serpentDecryptor (key, CryptoPP::Serpent::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcSerpentDecryptor (serpentDecryptor, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfSerpentDecryptor(cbcSerpentDecryptor, new CryptoPP::StringSink (ctext));// crash
    stfSerpentDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ctext.c_str() ), ctext.length() + 1);
    stfSerpentDecryptor.MessageEnd();


    return @(ctext.c_str());
}
```

1) How do I pass the key/IV as method parameters? See the commented code, that doesn't work...

2) I get a crash when trying to decrpyt

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext: StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size

Why? I thought decryption was automatic and the encryption will pad the plaintext accordingly...
I would also like to add a HMAC to the methods... This will be added after encryption and checked before decryption, correct?

Comment: Wondering why you have chosen "Serpent".

Comment: Very high security margin...

Comment: Interesting. Just checked with my Crypto domain expert: AES is a better choice and the goto choice for non-legacy usage. 3DES when DES compatibility is required. I assume you expert has a good reason for picking Serpent.

Comment: @NoOneInParticular Where are the flaws in crypto? Actually not in the encryption algorithm choice (assuming nothing really stupid). The attack is in the usage, flaws in the code, flaws in key handling/distribution, authentication, protocol and finally: humans. Who are the attackers: those to whom the value of the data is greater than the cost of breaking the crypto--and those with rubber hoses. Find the value of your data to others, spend enough to protect it. It is has substantial value get your code either written by or reviewed by a crypto domain expert--I do.

Comment: AES is not a better choice ... it's just the most common choice.. serpent is a better algo when it comes to security...

Comment: The encryption algorithm is not what will be attacked, not even the NSA attacks the AES, Serpent or 3DES with strict brute force. The extra code to bridge C++ to Objective-C is a nice target though, the more code, the more complicated the better for the attacker. The key being in memory is also a potential target and that is tough to get around if you use NSString and/or NSData. AES has a performance advantage with hardware instruction support but that probably would not make a meaningful difference unless there is a lot of encryption being done.

Comment: I know, I am thinking about using a very complex memory key management technique, (Schneier call it a bjoom , weird name but good idea ) . And I am thinking about making the Obective-C - C++ interface as small as posible... maybe this code will be used on android as well so it will be good to have the same crypto code on all apps.

Comment: BTW ... will the security level of the app be much better if I use Cryptanium code obfuscation/ anti-debugging ?

Comment: For a great book on how to use crypto see: "Cryptography Engineering: Design Principles and Practical Applications" by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier and Tadayoshi Kohno. Another reference book that is a standard (and a free download) is: [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) (My wife and I each have the printed version).

Comment: I read Cryptography Engineering. Great Book. Also read Applied Cryptography and Modern Cryptography...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get padding you have to do it yourself or have an API that supports standard paddings such as PKCS7. Base encryption, stream cyphers excepted, are block based, at the lower level there must be full blocks. Some higher level API provide padding.

I pass keys, iv and data `as NSData *` and access the bytes as `data.bytes`.
For cypher output data:

```
NSMutableData  *dataOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
// ...
                   dataOut.mutableBytes,
                   dataOut.length,
                   &cryptBytes
// ...
dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
```

I would make my API call similar to:

```
- (NSString *)encryptWithSerpentText:(NSString *)text key:(NSData *)key iv:(NSData *)iv;
```

The Mac is good but how will you validate it. Best to research best practices for authentication.

For HMAC just use the Apple supplied CommonCrypto library. CommonCrypto also supports: AES128, DES, 3DES, CAST, RC4 and Blowfish but not Serpent.

Finally, to get things working log each step, both in the  server and the client, that way the step that is failing with incorrect data can be found. In this case a straight C++ version against the hybrid Objective-C/C++ version.

Comment: Well Crypto++ does the padding... But when I get to the decryption method it seems to be missing... I'm thinking it's something to do with UTF8String ...

Comment: For an [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19930185/451475) of using NSData and crypto.

Comment: The question is how do I get the key from the NSData object into the key/iv array (of type byte) ...

Comment: You can use memcpy with data.out and data.length. You can also use `[data getBytes:&byteArray length:data.length];` `data.out` is just a pointer to a char. Objective-C is a strict superset of "C".